# χ² (chi-squared) statistic of scipy.stats.chi2_contingency vs sklearn.feature_selection.chi2

Tags: mathematical-statistics, scikit-learn, scipy

It appears from reading [Scikit-learn χ² (chi-squared) statistic and corresponding contingency table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21281328/scikit-learn-%CF%87%C2%B2-chi-squared-statistic-and-corresponding-contingency-table) that sklearn does not perform a standard contingency table analysis when calculating the χ² statistic between two categorical variables.

For example, given the data below

```
# libraries
import scipy.stats as sps
import pandas as pd

# data
data = pd.DataFrame({'gender': ['female']*60+['female']*54+['female']*46+['female']*41+['male']*40+['male']*44+['male']*53+['male']*57,
                     'education_level': ['high school']*60+['bachelors']*54+['masters']*46+['phd']*41+['high school']*40+['bachelors']*44+['masters']*53+['phd']*57})

# contingency table
contingency_table = pd.crosstab(index=data['gender'],
                                columns=data['education_level'])
```

[image: Contingency Table]

the χ² statistic

```
print(sps.chi2_contingency(contingency_table, correction=False))
```

is **8.0060** using scipy. This is the correct solution since it is doing an independent test.

If we were to instead use sklearn

```
# libraries
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.feature_selection import chi2

# label encoder for categorical features
le = LabelEncoder()

# transforming the categorical features
data.insert(2, 'education_level_le', pd.DataFrame(le.fit_transform(data['education_level'])))
data.insert(3, 'gender_le', pd.DataFrame(le.fit_transform(data['gender'])))
```

we would obtain

```
chi_2, p_value = chi2(data['education_level_le'].values.reshape(-1, 1), data['gender_le'].values)

print(chi_2)
```

a value of **4.6557**. This is an incorrect result because it represents a goodness-of-fit result rather than a test of independence. In theory, `scipy.stats.chisquare` should give the same result as `sklearn.feature_selection.chi2`.

**Which of these two methods is the appropriate one to use in order to determine whether the two categorical features are independent or not?** Are there any underlying assumptions of either method that makes one more suitable over the other one in this particular case?

I am trying to better understand why sklearn chose to implement their χ² calculation the way they did. Any links to other resources and papers will be appreciated.

**Updated (3/5/23)**: See sklearn issue with chi2: [should support categorical data other than binary or document count](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/21455). Additionally, it looks like the contingency matrix is a 2x2 matrix and you get a single p-val for the set of all the features in producing the target, whereas the feature_selection chi2 shows the p-vals for each feature independently of the others in producing the target. I believe that is why the two functions do not produce the same results.

**Updated (3/7/23)**: added commentary to each result explaining to why the two differ and why the first one is the correct one for answering the question related to an independence test.