# Cannot reproduce chi2 from scipy or sklearn

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, scikit-learn, scipy

Not only [don't sklearn and SciPy agree](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/549371/pearson-chi2-tests-of-independence-differences-between-scipy-and-scikit-learn) on the value they return for chi2, but they don't agree with an explicit implementation either (at least not always). Why is that?

Below is my code for generating a random data set of categorical features and targets, along with its corresponding contingency matrix. At the end, I compare the sklearn and SciPy with an explicit computation of chi2.

```
class CompareHypothesisTests():
    
    def __init__(
            self, n=10, n_features=3, f_cardinality=3, t_cardinality=2,
            f_name='f', t_name='t', threshold=.3):
        """
        This compares the statistics returned by different Python packages for
        the case when both the features and the target are categorical.

        Parameters
        ----------
        n : int, optional
            Number of examples.
        n_features : int, optional
            Number of features.
        f_cardinality : int, optional
            Cardinality of the feature space.
        t_cardinality :  int, optional
            Cardinality of the target space.
        f_name : int, optional
            Prefix of the feature names.
        t_name : TYPE, optional
            Prefix of the target name.
        threshold : int, optional
            Threshold beyond which the target changes values.

        Returns
        -------
        None.

        """
        
        self.n = n
        self.n_features = n_features
        self.f_cardinality = f_cardinality 
        self.t_cardinality = t_cardinality 
        self.f_name = f_name
        self.t_name = t_name
        self.threshold = threshold
        
        assert self.n_features >= 3
                       
    def __call__(self):
        
        self.generate_data()
        self.generate_contingency_matrix()
        self.hypothesis_test()

    def generate_data(self):
        
        """ 
        Generate the dataset `self.data`.
        """

        import numpy as np
        import pandas as pd                

        data = np.random.randint(
            0, self.f_cardinality, (self.n, self.n_features))
        
        data = pd.DataFrame(
            data,
            columns=[f'{self.f_name}{i}' for i in range(self.n_features)])
        data[self.t_name] = data.apply(
            lambda x: int(x[f'{self.f_name}0'] and x[f'{self.f_name}1'] 
            + x[f'{self.f_name}2'] > self.threshold), axis=1)
        
        self.data = data
        
    def generate_contingency_matrix(self):

        """ 
        Since both the features and the targets are categorical, generate the 
        contingency matrix `self.contingency`.
        """

        import pandas as pd
        
        tuples = []
        for f in range(self.n_features):
            tuples += [(f'{self.f_name}{f}', c) for 
                       c in range(self.f_cardinality)]

        contingency = pd.DataFrame(
            index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
                tuples, names=['feature', 'value']),
            columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
                [(self.t_name, c) for 
                 c in range(self.t_cardinality)]))
        
        # For each categorical feature...
        for fn in range(self.n_features):
            # for each possibly category of that feature...
            for f in range(self.f_cardinality):
                # for each possible category of the target...
                for t in range(self.t_cardinality):
                    # Compute the cardinality of the union between the feature
                    # category `f` and the target category `t`.
                    contingency.loc[(f'{self.f_name}{fn}', f), 
                                    (self.t_name, t)] = \
                        self.compute_contingency(fn, f, t)
            
        self.contingency = contingency
        
    def compute_contingency(self, fn , f, t):
        """
        Compute the contingency matrix between the categorical feature `fn` and 
        the categorical target `self.t_name`, whose values are .

        Parameters
        ----------
        fn : int, str
            Name of the feature.
        f : int, str
            Category of the feature.
        t : int, str
            Category of the target.

        Returns
        -------
        int
            Cardinality of the union between the feature category and target 
            category.

        """
        
        fn = f'{self.f_name}{fn}'
        data = self.data[[fn, self.t_name]].copy()
        data = data[data[fn] == f]
        data = data[data[f'{self.t_name}'] == t]
        
        return len(data)
    
    @staticmethod
    def chi2test(contingency):
        
        import numpy as np
        
        # print('\nContingency matrix:\n', contingency)
        mean = contingency.mean(axis=1)
        # print('\nMarginal mean:\n', mean)
        residuals = contingency.subtract(mean, axis=0)
        # print('\nSubtract the mean:\n', residuals)
        residuals = residuals.divide(np.sqrt(mean), axis=0)
        # print('\nDivide by the square root of the mean:\n', residuals)        
        residuals = residuals.pow(2)
        # print('\nTake the power of 2:\n', residuals)
        residuals = residuals.sum().sum()
        # print('\nSum over all entries:\n', residuals)
        
        return residuals, np.nan
        
    def hypothesis_test(self):
        
        import pandas as pd
        from scipy.stats import chi2_contingency
        from sklearn.feature_selection import chi2                 
        
        test_names = ['sklearn', 'SciPy', 'chi2test']
        
        # Multi-indexed data frame of the statistics.
        
        self.statistics = pd.DataFrame(
            index=[f'{self.f_name}{f}' for f in range(self.f_cardinality)],
            columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
                [('chi2', s) for s in test_names]
                +[('p-value', s) for s in test_names]))
        self.statistics = self.statistics.apply(
            lambda x: self.statistics.index, axis=0)

        # sklearn.feature_selection.chi2
        
        chi2, p_value = chi2(
            self.data[self.statistics.index.to_list()], 
            self.data[self.t_name])
        self.statistics[('chi2', 'sklearn')] = chi2
        self.statistics[('p-value', 'sklearn')] = p_value
        
        # scipy.stats.chi2_contingency
        
        for f in self.statistics.index:
            chi2, p_value, _, _ = chi2_contingency(self.contingency.loc[f])
            self.statistics.loc[f, ('chi2', 'SciPy')] = chi2
            self.statistics.loc[f, ('p-value', 'SciPy')] = p_value
            
        # chi2test
        
        for f in self.statistics.index:
            chi2, p_value = self.chi2test(self.contingency.loc[f])
            self.statistics.loc[f, ('chi2', 'chi2test')] = chi2
            self.statistics.loc[f, ('p-value', 'chi2test')] = p_value        
            
myTest = CompareHypothesisTests()
myTest()
print("\nData set:\n", myTest.data)
print("\nContingency matrix:\n", myTest.contingency)
print("\nResulting statistics:\n", myTest.statistics)
```

A sample run of the above returns the following summary. See how the chi2 values do not concord.

```
Data set:
    f0  f1  f2  t
0   0   2   0  0
1   1   1   1  1
2   1   1   2  1
3   0   0   1  0
4   2   0   1  1
5   2   0   2  1
6   1   1   2  1
7   0   1   0  0
8   1   0   2  1
9   2   2   1  1

Contingency matrix:
                t   
               0  1
feature value      
f0      0      3  0
        1      0  4
        2      0  3
f1      0      1  3
        1      1  3
        2      1  1
f2      0      2  0
        1      1  3
        2      0  4

Resulting statistics:
         chi2                      p-value                   
     sklearn     SciPy chi2test   sklearn     SciPy chi2test
f0  4.285714      10.0     10.0  0.038434  0.006738      NaN
f1  0.214286   0.47619      2.0  0.643429  0.788128      NaN
f2  2.682540  6.428571      7.0  0.101454  0.040184      NaN
```

Comment: Why did you compare to `scipy.stats.chi2_contingency` and not `scipy.stats.chisquare`?

Comment: @Tim To be frank, it's because I never understood how `scipy.stats.chisquare` works. I only understand chi2 if there is a contingency matrix involved, whereas `scipy.stats.chisquare` doesn't seem to require one. Does it matter, though? Why don't the values of chi2 concur in the example I gave?

Comment: Honestly, I didn't dive into the docs or your code, but you are comparing two different libraries and comparing to `chi2_contingency` while scikit-learn seems to use `chisquare` that, as noticed in the docs, seem to differ. You are also using your own implementation instead something standard like the implementation of contingency tables in `scipy.stats` so to answer it someone would need to compare differences in three different codebases. Maybe start with using `scipy.stats.chisquare`, and `scipy.stats.contingency` functionalities to factor out its issues with your code.

Comment: see also https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/591202/can-the-%cf%87%c2%b2-test-be-used-without-a-contingency-table/

Comment: @rep_ho I'm the author of that question too... It addresses a different issue, namely a blatant error in the implementation of `sklearn`'s version of the chi2 test.

Comment: To whoever closed this question: You need to remove the `scikit-learn`, `scipy` and `chi-squared-test` tags from Stats SE if you think this question is irrelevant. At least then you'd be coherent.

Comment: "*Not only don't sklearn and SciPy agree on the value they return for chi2, but they don't agree with an explicit implementation either (at least not always). Why is that?*". You'll find an answer here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/606925/164936 They are simply not the same test. I'd recommend to stay away from sklearn for any chi-squared hypothesis test. The sklearn implementation seems very idiosyncratic to this library, and probably not designed for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

As a test on completely different software I ran `tabchii` in Stata. I abbreviate output here but don't suppress the warnings. Good news: I can match SciPy, but there's an extra dimension to the problem that all these calculations ignore small expected frequencies.

```
. tabchii 3 0 \ 0 4 \ 0 3

6 cells with expected frequency < 5
2 cells with expected frequency < 1

         Pearson chi2(2) =  10.0000   Pr = 0.007
likelihood-ratio chi2(2) =  12.2173   Pr = 0.002

. tabchii 1 3 \ 1 3 \ 1 1

6 cells with expected frequency < 5
1 cell with expected frequency < 1

         Pearson chi2(2) =   0.4762   Pr = 0.788
likelihood-ratio chi2(2) =   0.4473   Pr = 0.800

. tabchii 2 0 \ 1 3 \ 0 4

6 cells with expected frequency < 5
1 cell with expected frequency < 1

         Pearson chi2(2) =   6.4286   Pr = 0.040
likelihood-ratio chi2(2) =   7.7186   Pr = 0.021
```